# Remote server synchronization with local Github repository

Tags: git, github, synchronization, local

I have been working on project with 3 more people from one main repository (forked one main) and we are all working on one dev server. Main problem that we have is local to remote synchronization when testing code. I'm using NetBeans as editor and NetBeans have nice sync tool but sometimes get a little bit mad and do not sync well, so I was google for some rsync scripts that will sync code from my local repository to remote server.

Basically, I need some sh script that will determine what file is changed and push that file to server, while testing and if everything is ok on server, I'll push changes to my GitHub repository. I found some lftp script and rsync script but that did not work because I do not know sh as well. So, every help is appreciate .

Thanks to all of you.

Comment: please add details about why it doesn't work; rsync is quite simple and should work fine.

Comment: Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code, and all **relevant** error messages exactly as they appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up git on the remote server, add a remote for the server, and then commit and push to that. rsync should also work if used correctly.